# Segmentation fault in sort function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stdvector

I am working on a code that sorts a 2d vector based on it's first column, The code gives out a segmentation fault on the input

```
6
7 1 3 4 1 7
```

Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool sortcol(const vector <int> v1,const vector <int> v2){
 return v1[0]<v2[0];
}
int main() {
int n;
cin>>n;
vector < vector<int> > v(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
    vector <int> temp2;
    int temp;
    cin>>temp;
    temp2.push_back(temp);
    temp2.push_back(i);
    v.push_back(temp2);
}
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),sortcol);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't pass `vector` by value to your custom comparer. And what if the vector is empty?

Comment: Replace `vector < vector<int> > v(n);` with `vector < vector<int> > v;` Right now you end up with a vector with 12 vectors and the first 6 of them are actually empty.

Comment: `v` contains `n` empty vectors (from `v(n)`) followed by `n` two-element vectors (from `push_back`s). Drop the `(n)` initializer.

Comment: @DimChtz why are 12 vectors created when n is only 6?
Okay, gotit since I am pushing back the original 6 vectors are empty and iam adding 6 vectors with values in them.

Comment: @Vishal because you need to read what people told you in 2 answers and comments and comprehend it.

Comment: @Vishal The first six are created on the declaration line; the other six are created in the loop in `push_back` calls.

Comment: You create v(6) with 6 empty vectors and then you add 6 more in the loop.

Comment: Side question: why are you using vectors for your pairs, rather than `std::pair<int, int>`? So much ugliness goes away. Pairs even compare the way you'd want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this declaration of your vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> v(n);
```

It does not simply reserve `n` spots, it creates a vector with `n` empty vectors inside. Hence the first call to `sortcol` for any of these empty entries produces undefined behavior, because

```
return v1[0] < v2[0];
```

references non-existent element at position zero.

Replace the declaration with

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
```

to fix this problem. If you would like to reserve space for `n` entries, add a call to [`vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) after the declaration:

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
v.reserve(n);
```

You should also pass vectors to your comparator by const reference, rather than by const value.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to reserve the wrong way in this particular case. Use

```
    v.reserve(n);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator has 2 issues:

```
bool sortcol(const vector <int> v1,const vector <int> v2){
   return v1[0]<v2[0];
}
```

- it does not check if vectors passed to it do have at least one element
- you should pass vectors by const reference (this is not error, but can lead to bad performance issue)

So in your code:

```
vector < vector<int> > v(n);
```

you create `v` with `n` empty vectors and then you push back additional data after it. Then you try to sort it and you get UB with your comparator when it hits empty vectors you created.